# XPath function normalize-space() and starts-with() don't find etem with &nbsp; right befor item

Tags: xpath

I have piece of  such HTML code

```
<td>
<a href="CMenu?op=m&menuID=42&rurl={{rurl}}" title="Edit menu">
<img border="0" alt="" src="Images/application.gif">
&nbsp;Case
</a>
</td>
```

and need to find text "Case".
I use different XPath Queries, but no one is good, all find nothing:

```
//a[text() = ' Case']
//a[text() = 'Case']
//td/a[normalize-space(text()) = 'Case']
//td[a[normalize-space(.) = 'Case']]
//td[a[normalize-space(text()) = 'Case']]
//*[starts-with(.," Case")]
//*[starts-with(.,"Case")]
```

But, when I try to find this item with

```
//a[contains(.,'Case') and string-length() = 5]
```

It works, but I can not accept hard code '5', I want make this XPath multipurpose for other relative items.
And if I use

```
//a[contains(.,'Case')]
```

I find a lists of items which contains 'Case', but need only one with 'Case' and not more chars.
Maybe I do something wrong, just want take it clear to me.

---

My colleague tell me that I can use this one XPath

```
//a[substring(text(),2)='Case']
```

just skip this space. I find out that it's work! but seems to me there is another way to solve my problem with out any skip or pass.

Answer (score 4):

**Use**:

```
/td/a
      [starts-with(normalize-space(), '&#xA0;Case')]
```

**XPath isn't entities-aware and `normalize-space()` by definition only processes white-space characters**: space, NL, CR and Tab -- so `&#xA0;` (which is to what the entity `&nbsp;` is expanded) isn't considered a whitespace character.

**XSLT - based verification**:

**This transformation selects with the above XPath expression and outputs the result**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
  "/td/a
      [starts-with(normalize-space(), '&#xA0;Case')]
   "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<td>
<a href="CMenu?op=m&amp;menuID=42&amp;rurl={{rurl}}" title="Edit menu">
<img border="0" alt="" src="Images/application.gif"/>
&#xA0;Case
</a>
</td>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<a href="CMenu?op=m&amp;menuID=42&amp;rurl={{rurl}}" title="Edit menu">
  <img border="0" alt="" src="Images/application.gif" />
 Case
</a>
```

Comment: @_DimitreNovatchev I try to use your XPath, but it doesn't work on my code :-(
Nevertheless, thanks to all, I find my way to solve this problem
//td/a[starts-with(., 'Alt+0160Case')]
I just replace hard space (&nbsp;) with combination of keyboard Alt + 0 1 6 0. It's not clear for code - but it work.

Comment: @Sergey K: If your XPath engine is W3C - compliant, my solution should work -- you need just to copy and paste this XPath expression.

Comment: @_DimitreNovatchev: can you tel me how I can get XPath engine version, or where I can see it? is it W3C - compliant? And is it possibly to install other engine? Sorry for such question, I'm novice in XPath

Comment: @Sergey K: I have updated my answer -- slightly changed the XPath expression to eliminate the whitespace that actually precedes the string. I also provide an XSLT-based verification that proves the XPath expression selects the wanted node. Please, try it.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to try //a[matches(., '^\W*Case\W*$')] which will match a elements with value "Case" possibly surrounded by some other non-word characters (anything but letters, numbers and _ I think).

Comment: @_Mike: That's XPath 2.0 and very few people have it available. Also, the OP wanted to use `starts-with()` -- just look at the title of his question.

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't aware of the XPath 2.0 restriction.  I should point out the OP asked for normalize-space() too, and your solution doesn't use that :)  Just trying to provide some alternative.

Comment: @_Mike: Of course, my answer reflects on the OP's wish to use `normalize-space()` and explains why in this case `normalize-space()` doesn't produce the results he's expecting. It's not true that I ignore the "`normalize-space()` part" - on the contrary.